# Пользователь умер. Как удалить (заблокировать) пользователя?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Предположим, что некий пользователь данного сайта умер, отсюда вопрос: существует ли возможность удалить его аккаунт (именно аккаунт, а не сообщения), не имея доступа к его почте?

Как в принципе в таких случаях действует администрация и имеется ли у неё подобный опыт в обработке таких запросов со стороны родственников или знакомых умершего?

**Дополнено**

Вопрос не про **зачем?**, а **каким образом?**

Comment: А смысл в подобном удалении? На сайте уже имеется большое количество учётных записей, неактивных более года, и никаких проблем ни сайт, ни посетители, ни (похоже) владельцы этих учётных записей не испытывают.

Comment: @Arhad это уже личный вопрос мотивации близких. Сам же вопрос не об этом.

Comment: Можно написать через [форму обратной связи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), но я дал знать управляющему сообществом (Николас Чабановский, представитель компании StackExchange Inc.), так что он ответит вам здесь.

Comment: Не, ну а всё-таки зачем :) Ящитаю, пользователя достаточно заблокировать, опционально повесить инфу о смерти где-нибудь в профиле

Comment: пользователь жив пока его сообщения приносят пользу

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38742/309650

Comment: Ваш аккаунт и ваши ответы на SO вам не принадлежат. Они называют это "общественным достоянием".

Comment: @Suvitruf ну тогда напишите всем здесь Ваши доступа к своему аккаунту, раз это это "общественное достояние".

Comment: @edem я тут причём? Я лишь цитирую, мне подобная политика самому не совсем по душе.

Comment: @Suvitruf такими комментариями о том, что аккаунты пользователей им не принадлежат, можно легко запутать читателей, а вот ответы частично да, доступны многим, но вот авторские права, в виде имени автора, написавшего ответ, за ним сохраняются.

Comment: @edem вы даже удалить аккаунт свой не можете. При удалении аккаунта все ответы/вопросы останутся.

Comment: @Suvitruf аккаунт и сообщения на SO, определенно, принадлежат его владельцу. Владелец лишь передает часть прав на них компании Stack Exchange по лицензии Creative Commons (что не позволяет взять и удалить все свои сообщения), но это не равнозначно "общественному достоянию"

Comment: @Suvitruf "лишь цитирую" полагается сопровождать ссылкой на первоисточник. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @D-side эти люди могут обидеться.

Answer (score 7):

Этого делать **не нужно**. В противном случае получится ситуация когда можно заблокировать навсегда любого пользователя написав в поддержку что он умер.

Доверять письмам случайных людей утверждающих что они родственники больше чем выбранным пользователем способам входа - некорректно.

Comment: По такой логике и аккаунты не надо восстанавливать, когда человек пишет в поддержку, что потерял доступ к своей почте.

Comment: @edem совершенно верно.

Answer (score 7):

Я полагаю, что надо придерживаться политики соц.сетей применяемую в отношении умерших членов, в частности [политика facebook такая](https://www.facebook.com/help/103897939701143)

Основная идея: аккаунт умершего юзера не удаляется, если только при жизни юзер не попросил его удалить после смерти, сам аккаунт переводится в статус "памятного", то есть никто не может войти в аккаунт и его невозможно изменить.

Понятно, что не все положения применимы по отношению к SO, тем не менее - основной посыл: не удалять аккаунт, очевидно, полностью применим к SO.

Comment: Да, в таком варианте это было бы приемлемо. Вопрос в механизме взаимодействия с администрацией.

Answer (score 5):

А зачем его аккаунт удалять? Пусть остаётся.

При удалении аккаунта все его сообщения станут анонимными (точнее, там будет написано "user" и кучка цифр, например, `user123456`). Я не вижу причин, по которым следовало бы поступить так со всеми его сообщениями. Человек внёс вклад в сообщество и вполне заслуживает, чтобы его сообщения были подписаны его именем.

PS: А о существовании функциональности по удалению пользователей написано в справке.

Comment: И где там написано об удалении "чужого" аккаунта другими людьми?

Comment: Ну значит как-то заблокировать аккаунт, чтобы только имя и осталось и большего им никто не смог бы воспользоваться.

Comment: @edem, там говорится, что есть техническая возможность удалить аккаунт. А что касается удаления по запросу других людей - про это там ничего нет.

Comment: @edem, а как им могут воспользоваться, если пароль неизвестен?

Comment: Например, мне не нужно знать пароли некого человека, чтобы зайти под его аккаунтом, достаточно пустить меня к его компьютеру с открытым браузером, скажем, когда он пошёл на обед, не выключив комп. Ну что за вопрос?! Пароль не панацея.